# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier in a two TableView View Controller Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using two `TableViews` in a `ViewController` but I get this error when it gets to the second `TableViewCell`, `cartProductCell`. They both have custom classes, and outlets, as it was the problem for many in other posts. Is the first time I'm doing this and I can't find a solution for this. May it be just because I'm using custom classes for the cells? In the tutorials I found about two TableViews weren't used custom classes.

In the Storyboard editor everything is connected well and identifiers are both correct.
Here's the function:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?

//        if tableView == self.worksTableView && CartViewController.bookedWoksArray.count > 0 {
        if tableView == self.worksTableView  {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartWorkCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CartWorkTableViewCell
            cell.workImageView.image = CartViewController.bookedWoksArray[indexPath.row].0
            cell.workNameLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].1
            cell.workPriceLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedWoksArray[indexPath.row].2

        } // else {return}

//         else if tableView == self.worksTableView && CartViewController.bookedProductsArray.count > 0 {
        if tableView == self.worksTableView {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartProductCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CartProductTableViewCell

            cell.cartProductImageView.image = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].0
            cell.cartProductNameLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].1
            cell.cartProductPriceLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].2
        } //else {return}
        return cell!

    }
```

As usual many thanks

Comment: Unrelated but both `as IndexPath` casts are redundant. `indexPath` **is** `IndexPath`. And you are discouraged from using tuples as data source object.

Comment: Why are you checking `if tableView == self.worksTableView` twice?

Comment: @AaronBrager Good catch. That's most likely the error reason.

Comment: Also it looks like you’re shadowing the outer `cell` with a new variable with the same name inside the conditional blocks.

Comment: @AaronBrager. thanks for seeing it. I get a nil error now on returning cell, but the arrays are populated. Any Ideas why?

Comment: @vadian. Why is it a bad idea to use tuples as data source?

Comment: Please read the first `Note` in [Swift Language Guide: The Basics - Tuples](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329)

Comment: @vadian. I see what you mean, but I'm using them as temporary data. Indeed for persisting data I will use a Struct or a class, as it will be the result of these two table views combined

Comment: A tuple as data source array is **not** temporary data.

Comment: I Know, but I'll empty them as soon as I used the data in them, I use them as temporary data storage that way. Is it very wrong?

Comment: I did sort the cells problem out by giving them a unique name and assigning `cell` the value in the if closure. `cell = workCell` not sure is an elegant way to solve it dough.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries and after fixing a silly mistake I finally made it work by assigning the value of custom cells to `cell` and the function's code is now:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?

        if tableView == self.worksTableView  {

            let workCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartWorkCell", for: indexPath) as! CartWorkTableViewCell
            workCell.workImageView.image = CartViewController.bookedWoksArray[indexPath.row].0
            workCell.workNameLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedWoksArray[indexPath.row].1
            workCell.workPriceLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedWoksArray[indexPath.row].2
            cell = workCell
        } 

        if tableView == self.productsTableView{


            let productCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartProductCell", for: indexPath) as! CartProductTableViewCell

            productCell.cartProductImageView.image = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].0
            productCell.cartProductNameLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].1
            productCell.cartProductPriceLabel.text = CartViewController.bookedProductsArray[indexPath.row].2
            cell = productCell
        }
        return cell!

    }
```